# Two dimensional Array in Z3 solver

Tags: arrays, z3

I want to define an two dimensional array as following using z3 solver using C API

a[3][3] = { {0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}

How to define this using Z3 solver C API where in i need to add constraints such as sum of each rows is equal to 1 and sum of each coloums should me <= 100.

Answer (score 5):

Z3 supports the array theory, but is usually used to encode unbounded arrays, or arrays that are very big. This issue has been discussed in other posts (See: [Create an array with fixed size and initialize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068561/how-to-create-an-array-with-fixed-size-and-initialize-it)). If we search for `[z3] array`, we will find many other posts.
For arrays of a predefined size, it is easier (and more efficient) to create "arrays of Z3 expressions". The Sudoku example in the [Z3 tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/guide) shows how to do it.
Here is the Python code for the problem described in your post (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/h1R)).

```py
# 3x3 matrix of integer variables
A = [ [ Int("a_%s_%s" % (i+1, j+1)) for j in range(3) ] 
      for i in range(3) ]
print A

# Rows constraints
rows_c = [ Sum(r) == 1 for r in A ]
print rows_c

# Columns constraints
A_transpose = [ [ A[i][j] for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]
cols_c = [ Sum(c) <= 10 for c in A_transpose ]
print cols_c

s = Solver()
s.add(rows_c)
s.add(cols_c)
# solve constraints
print s.check()
# print solution
m = s.model()
print m
# printing the solution in a nicer way
r = [ [ m.evaluate(A[i][j]) for j in range(3) ] for i in range(3) ]
print_matrix(r)
```

Comment: Thanks Leonardo,Could you help me to show a solution with  C-code for two dimensional arrays.above we did it in Python earlier.