# Z3 Array in C language not python

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, z3

Kind request dont answer if you doesnt know about Z3 solver.i posted this questions earlier some answers like how to implement array in C poped up.There are some people who developed Z3 solver in this forum.Its Intended to them.If you dont know Z3 solver please avoid to reply for this question.

I have posted this question earlier and got solution as in Python.we had implemented the below problem already in python.we are trying to port Z3 solver to integrate Z3 solver to a in house tool as part of my thesis.Could you help me to show a solution for below requirement in "C" language not in python.

I want to define and create a two dimensional array as following using z3 solver using C API

example : a[3][3] 
How to define this using Z3 solver C API where in i need to add constraints such as

elements of the two dimensional arrays only 0 or 1.
sum of each rows is equal to 1
sum of each columns(controller memory) should me <= 100
the problem what am trying to solve is, i have two arrays in which one is a[sw]={50,25,100,75} which represents the data produced(50kb) by each functions.b[cont]={100,100,100} controllers with memory(kb) capacity.we are trying to generate a[4][3] matrix with shows the function allocation to the controllers satisfying the above mentioned constraints

sample output(this can be one configuration out of so many) for above problem.but its a valid configuration

a[sw][cont] =

A  B   C
A 1  0  0 
B 1  0  0
C 0  1  0
D 0  0  1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Z3 Python API is implemented on top of the C API. Any Z3 example written in Python can be converted into C/C++. However, the Z3 Python API is much more convenient to use, and Python list comprehensions simplify the encoding. Here is one way of encoding the Python example ([Two dimensional Array in Z3 solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055165/two-dimensional-array-in-z3-solver)) in C++.
The main differences are: I'm using `std::vector` instead of lists, and for-loops instead of list comprehensions.

```cpp
void cpp_vector_example() {
    context c;
    unsigned n = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<expr> > A;
    // Create a nxn matrix of Z3 integer constants
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A.push_back(std::vector<expr>());
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            char name[100];
            sprintf(name, "a_%d_%d", i, j);
            A[i].push_back(c.int_const(name));
        }
    }

    solver s(c);

    // Add constraint: the sum of each row is one
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        expr sum(c);
        sum = A[i][0];
        for (unsigned j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            sum = sum + A[i][j];
        }
        s.add(sum == 1);
    }

    // Add constraint: the sum of each column is less than 100
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        expr sum(c);
        sum = A[0][j];
        for (unsigned i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            sum = sum + A[i][j];
        }
        s.add(sum <= 100);
    }

    // Add constraint: for each a_i_j in the matrix, 0 <= a_i_j <= 10
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (unsigned i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            s.add(0 <= A[i][j]);
            s.add(A[i][j] <= 100);
        }
    }

    // Display constraints added to solver s.
    std::cout << s << "\n";

    // Solve constraints
    std::cout << s.check() << "\n";

    // Print solution (aka model)
    model m = s.get_model();
    std::cout << m << "\n";

    // Print result as a matrix
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            std::cout << m.eval(A[i][j]) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```