# An efficient way to nest store operations

Tags: z3

In [Most efficient way to represent memory buffers in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24062292/1892814) the question on how make nested store operations more efficient is answered that one can replace the (nested) store operations with selects as in: `(assert (= (select A i1) v1))`. However, I need the store operation because previous constraints have to be replaced with the new constraints.

For example: the following constraints simulate the following assembly program:

```
mov qword ptr [rax], rbx
mov rcx, qword ptr [rax]
```

I like to proof that rbx and rcx are equal, I assert (= RBX!2 RCX!2) and expect that the model can be satisfied. This works perfectly. I assert (not (= RBX!2 RCX!2)) and expect that the model cannot be satisfied. When I feed the following constraints to Z3 (eg [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3)) it gives an almost instant answer: UNSAT. However, if I proof the same problem in a C# program (see below) it cannot deduce UNSAT (in reasonable time).

**Question**: What can I try to make the C# program as quick as the SMT2.0 program?

```
(declare-fun RAX!0 () (_ BitVec 64))
(declare-fun RAX!1 () (_ BitVec 64))
(declare-fun RAX!2 () (_ BitVec 64))

(declare-fun RBX!0 () (_ BitVec 64))
(declare-fun RBX!1 () (_ BitVec 64))
(declare-fun RBX!2 () (_ BitVec 64))

(declare-fun RCX!0 () (_ BitVec 64))
(declare-fun RCX!1 () (_ BitVec 64))
(declare-fun RCX!2 () (_ BitVec 64))

(declare-fun MEM!0 () (Array (_ BitVec 64) (_ BitVec 8)))
(declare-fun MEM!1 () (Array (_ BitVec 64) (_ BitVec 8)))
(declare-fun MEM!2 () (Array (_ BitVec 64) (_ BitVec 8)))

(assert (= RAX!1 RAX!0))
(assert (= RBX!1 RBX!0))
(assert (= RCX!1 RCX!0))
(assert (let ((a!1 (store (store (store MEM!0 RAX!0 ((_ extract 7 0) RBX!0))
                         (bvadd #x0000000000000001 RAX!0)
                         ((_ extract 15 8) RBX!0))
                  (bvadd #x0000000000000002 RAX!0)
                  ((_ extract 23 16) RBX!0))))
(let ((a!2 (store (store (store a!1
                                (bvadd #x0000000000000003 RAX!0)
                                ((_ extract 31 24) RBX!0))
                         (bvadd #x0000000000000004 RAX!0)
                         ((_ extract 39 32) RBX!0))
                  (bvadd #x0000000000000005 RAX!0)
                  ((_ extract 47 40) RBX!0))))
  (= MEM!1
     (store (store a!2
                   (bvadd #x0000000000000006 RAX!0)
                   ((_ extract 55 48) RBX!0))
            (bvadd #x0000000000000007 RAX!0)
            ((_ extract 63 56) RBX!0))))))
(assert (= RAX!2 RAX!1))
(assert (= RBX!2 RBX!1))
(assert (= RCX!2
   (concat (select MEM!1 (bvadd #x0000000000000007 RAX!1))
           (select MEM!1 (bvadd #x0000000000000006 RAX!1))
           (select MEM!1 (bvadd #x0000000000000005 RAX!1))
           (select MEM!1 (bvadd #x0000000000000004 RAX!1))
           (select MEM!1 (bvadd #x0000000000000003 RAX!1))
           (select MEM!1 (bvadd #x0000000000000002 RAX!1))
           (select MEM!1 (bvadd #x0000000000000001 RAX!1))
           (select MEM!1 RAX!1))))
(assert (= MEM!2 MEM!1))
(assert (not (= RBX!2 RCX!2)))
```

C# code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "unsat-core", "false" },    // enable generation of unsat cores
    { "model", "false" },         // enable model generation
    { "proof", "false" },         // enable proof generation
    { "timeout", "60000" }        // 60000=1min
};
Context ctx = new Context(settings);

Solver solver = ctx.MkSolver(ctx.MkTactic("qfbv"));
BitVecExpr rax0 = ctx.MkBVConst("RAX!0", 64);
BitVecExpr rax1 = ctx.MkBVConst("RAX!1", 64);
BitVecExpr rax2 = ctx.MkBVConst("RAX!2", 64);

BitVecExpr rbx0 = ctx.MkBVConst("RBX!0", 64);
BitVecExpr rbx1 = ctx.MkBVConst("RBX!1", 64);
BitVecExpr rbx2 = ctx.MkBVConst("RBX!2", 64);

BitVecExpr rcx0 = ctx.MkBVConst("RCX!0", 64);
BitVecExpr rcx1 = ctx.MkBVConst("RCX!1", 64);
BitVecExpr rcx2 = ctx.MkBVConst("RCX!2", 64);

ArrayExpr mem0 = ctx.MkArrayConst("MEM!0", ctx.MkBitVecSort(64), ctx.MkBitVecSort(8));
ArrayExpr mem1 = ctx.MkArrayConst("MEM!1", ctx.MkBitVecSort(64), ctx.MkBitVecSort(8));
ArrayExpr mem2 = ctx.MkArrayConst("MEM!2", ctx.MkBitVecSort(64), ctx.MkBitVecSort(8));

solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(rax1, rax0));
solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(rbx1, rbx0));
solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(rcx1, rcx0));
ArrayExpr memX0 = ctx.MkStore(mem0, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(0, 64), rax0), ctx.MkExtract((1 * 8) - 1, 0 * 8, rbx0));
ArrayExpr memX1 = ctx.MkStore(memX0, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(1, 64), rax0), ctx.MkExtract((2 * 8) - 1, 1 * 8, rbx0));
ArrayExpr memX2 = ctx.MkStore(memX1, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(2, 64), rax0), ctx.MkExtract((3 * 8) - 1, 2 * 8, rbx0));
ArrayExpr memX3 = ctx.MkStore(memX2, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(3, 64), rax0), ctx.MkExtract((4 * 8) - 1, 3 * 8, rbx0));
ArrayExpr memX4 = ctx.MkStore(memX3, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(4, 64), rax0), ctx.MkExtract((5 * 8) - 1, 4 * 8, rbx0));
ArrayExpr memX5 = ctx.MkStore(memX4, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(5, 64), rax0), ctx.MkExtract((6 * 8) - 1, 5 * 8, rbx0));
ArrayExpr memX6 = ctx.MkStore(memX5, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(6, 64), rax0), ctx.MkExtract((7 * 8) - 1, 6 * 8, rbx0));
memX7 = ctx.MkStore(memX6, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(7, 64), rax0), ctx.MkExtract((8 * 8) - 1, 7 * 8, rbx0));
solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(mem1, memX7).Simplify() as BoolExpr);

solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(rax2, rax1));
solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(rbx2, rbx1));
BitVecExpr y0 = ctx.MkSelect(mem1, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(0, 64), rax1)) as BitVecExpr;
BitVecExpr y1 = ctx.MkSelect(mem1, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(1, 64), rax1)) as BitVecExpr;
BitVecExpr y2 = ctx.MkSelect(mem1, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(2, 64), rax1)) as BitVecExpr;
BitVecExpr y3 = ctx.MkSelect(mem1, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(3, 64), rax1)) as BitVecExpr;
BitVecExpr y4 = ctx.MkSelect(mem1, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(4, 64), rax1)) as BitVecExpr;
BitVecExpr y5 = ctx.MkSelect(mem1, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(5, 64), rax1)) as BitVecExpr;
BitVecExpr y6 = ctx.MkSelect(mem1, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(6, 64), rax1)) as BitVecExpr;
BitVecExpr y7 = ctx.MkSelect(mem1, ctx.MkBVAdd(ctx.MkBV(7, 64), rax1)) as BitVecExpr;
BitVecExpr y = ctx.MkConcat(y7, ctx.MkConcat(y6, ctx.MkConcat(y5, ctx.MkConcat(y4, ctx.MkConcat(y3, ctx.MkConcat(y2, ctx.MkConcat(y1, y0)))))));
solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(rcx2, y).Simplify() as BoolExpr);
solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(mem2, mem1));

Status status_Neg = solver.Check(ctx.MkNot(ctx.MkEq(rbx2, rcx2)));
Console.WriteLine("Status Neg = "+status_Neg); // Go on holiday...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a way to run the C# program to play with it, unfortunately. But I noticed that you had calls to `Simplify`:

```
solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(mem1, memX7).Simplify() as BoolExpr);
```

I'm curious why you needed that call? Perhaps that's the culprit?

The other thing to try would be to use uninterpreted functions for representing memory, instead of `Array`s. UF's are typically much easier to deal with, and they provide roughly the same abstraction in my personal experience.

It might be a good idea to look at what the C# interface generated as SMT-Lib, to see if the translation is significantly different than what you thought it would be. I guess you could do that using the following function: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/dotnet/AST.cs#L195

Comment: The Simplify was an experiment, It did not change the Expr on which it was called, and I (incorrectly) assumed that it thus wouldn't matter much. It does matter much but it still does not explain why the SMT2.0 version is 0.05 sec while the c# version is 20 sec.

Comment: My functional programming experience (Lambda calculus & Haskell) is a bit rusty. Could you please give a hint how such an uninterpreted function for storing a value (8-bits bitvec) to an address (64-bits bitvec) would look like such that a previous value would be overwritten. The destructive write makes it difficult to understand (for me).

Comment: Sorry, my comment was misleading. By "uninterpreted function" I did not mean SMTLib UFs. Instead, I meant keeping track of the memory structure yourself;  only generating values that are accessed. In a sense, you'll be doing coding outside of SMTLib, and translating the "trace" of an execution down to SMTLib. I'm not familiar with the C# interface, but if you're willing to try Haskell, I can help with coding this using SBV. (http://leventerkok.github.io/sbv/).  This example, in particular, seems relevant: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-6.1/docs/Data-SBV-Examples-BitPrecise-Legato.html