# Why does Z3 not solve this simple script with arrays and quantifiers?

Tags: z3

Here is a small Z3 problem that returns unknown (timeout), both in a locally built Z3 4.6.0 and on https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial:

```
(declare-const m1 (Array String Int))
(declare-const m2 (Array String Int))
(declare-const c Int)
(assert (or (= c 11) (= c 12)))
(assert (forall ((x String)) (= (select m1 x) 0)))
(assert (= (select m2 "0") 42))
(assert (forall ((x String)) (or (= x "0") (= (select m2 x) 0))))
(assert (= m2 (ite (= c 11) (store m1 "1" 100) (store m1 "0" 42))))
(check-sat)
```

I'm curious why z3 is not able to prove it. How is Z3 processing this problem and is there a way I can determine what Z3 is trying to do? When I run with -v:15, I see output like this:

```
(smt.restarting :propagations 0 :decisions 903 :conflicts 1 :restart 100 :agility 0.00)
(smt.mbqi)
(smt.propagate-values)
(smt.nnf-cnf)
(smt.reduce-asserted)
(smt.lift-ite)
(smt.maximizing-bv-sharing)
(smt.reduce-asserted)
(smt.simplifier-done)
(smt.searching)
(smt.simplifying-clause-set :num-deleted-clauses 84)
(smt.propagate-values)
(smt.nnf-cnf)
(smt.reduce-asserted)
(smt.lift-ite)
(smt.maximizing-bv-sharing)
(smt.reduce-asserted)
(smt.simplifier-done)
(smt.searching)
(smt.mbqi :failed k!8)
(smt.propagate-values)
(smt.nnf-cnf)
(smt.reduce-asserted)
(smt.lift-ite)
(smt.maximizing-bv-sharing)
(smt.reduce-asserted)
(smt.simplifier-done)
(smt.searching)
(smt.simplifying-clause-set :num-deleted-clauses 82)
(smt.propagate-values)
(smt.nnf-cnf)
(smt.reduce-asserted)
(smt.lift-ite)
(smt.maximizing-bv-sharing)
(smt.reduce-asserted)
(smt.simplifier-done)
(smt.searching)
(smt.mbqi :failed k!10)
(smt.restarting :propagations 0 :decisions 946 :conflicts 1 :restart 100 :agility 0.00)
^C(tactic-exception "canceled")
```

I'm not entirely sure what to make of that output. Is there a way to see more info on Z3's state at each of these points?

When I change the problem slightly to the following, it finishes immediately:

```
(declare-const m1 (Array String Int))
(declare-const m2 (Array String Int))
(declare-const c Int)
(assert (= c 12)) ; or (= c 11)
(assert (forall ((x String)) (= (select m1 x) 0)))
(assert (= (select m2 "0") 42))
(assert (forall ((x String)) (or (= x "0") (= (select m2 x) 0))))
(assert (= m2 (ite (= c 11) (store m1 "1" 100) (store m1 "0" 42))))
(check-sat)
```

Can the first problem be fixed (while letting c be indeterminate to solve for), while still requiring that m1 is 0 for all values and m2 is 0 on all values other than "0", e.g. by applying appropriate tactics or quantifier patterns?

Answer (score 1):

For declaring constant arrays, you should prefer the `const` struct, instead of going through quantifiers. That is, replace:

```
(assert (forall ((x String)) (= (select m1 x) 0)))
```

with:

```
(assert (= m1 ((as const (Array String Int)) 0)))
```

You'll notice that z3 can now handle your query with ease.

Constant arrays are explained in the Z3 guide: https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h26

Comment: Thanks, but I am interested in an application in which the starting array is not always just all 0 (that was just for an example), and I wanted to avoid nested stores, due to the performance of that, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062292/most-efficient-way-to-represent-memory-buffers-in-z3?noredirect=1&lq=1.   

So I am still curious (a) why Z3 does not solve the problem with quantifiers, and (b) how to understand the output and interact with Z3 in order to see where it is going wrong myself (teach me to fish :)).