# how I can to know how many values have a array in z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using Z3py but when I define a array

`array = Array('array', IntSort(), IntSort())`

I don't know how I can to know how many values have the array.

Comment: Try to use the build-in `len(array)` function, if this is not working just try to look which attributes are available for array object, `dir(array)`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Z3 (and in SMT) are of unbounded size. See, for instance, [Create an array with fixed size and initialize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068561/create-an-array-with-fixed-size-and-initialize-it)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but If I define 5 instances of "array" how I can to know that exist 5 instances? For example `array[0] = ... ,array[1]  = ... , array[2] = ..., array[3] = ... , array[4] = ... ` then, if I use for example a value like int i = 5, how can I compare with i if the number of instances of array are 5 or less?

Comment: As Christoph mentioned, an array from `IntSort` to `IntSort` will be defined for every integer element. (It's more like a function in that sense.) So, asking "5 or less" is meaningless. The answer is, it's always more than 5: It has an element for every integer value. Do not conflate it with arrays as found in languages like C or Java.